# Is there a way for Tasker to notify me when a background app is using the voice recorder or the camera?

Tags: tasker

Is there a way for Tasker to notify me when a background app is using the voice recorder or the camera?

I'm trying to find out which app is accessing the voice recorder in the background. Sometimes when I use the video recorder, I get a message saying the voice recorder is being used by another app.

Comment: Trying to find out which app is accessing the voice recorder in the background. Sometimes when I go to use the video recorder, I get a message saying the voice recorder is being used by another app.

Comment: Are you concerned about your privacy? If so then I have a solution to prevent apps from accessing those features and will provide an answer for you.

Comment: I'll give you a bigger hint, though it requires a rooted Android. The system service `media.camera` would show the PID of the process currently using the camera (front/rear individually). The service `media.player` would give you the PID of the process currently recording voice from microphone and saving it into a file. It doesn't seem to mention a process if the latter is not saving the input in a file. I may be wrong though. `media_router` may also come handy. All of them can be accessed using `dumpsys` command. E.g. `dumpsys media.camera`.

Answer (score 0):

Tasker cannot interact with background apps, and thus cannot detect if a background app is active or using the voice recorder. What Tasker can do, via [Tasker Process Running (KC)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kc.tasker.processes&hl=en) is detect what processes, including apps, are running. if you store this data in some way whenever the error appears, you can look for correlations between running processes and the error.

Note: Have you Googled around to see if your error is common with your device, app, or OS version?

Comment: If I am not mistaken Tasker Process Running checks if a particular app is running, it doesn't dump a list of running apps. So he should manually create a task that checks if each app is running or not, and store the results in a boolean array.